# Google Analytics - block outgoing links

Tags: google-analytics, hyperlink, tracking

I'm building a site which contains external links, however, I don't want any links from my website to show up in another site's Google Analytics tracking.
For example, if www.site1.com links to www.site2.com I don't want the link from www.site1.com to show up as link referral or source.

Not sure if this is possible.

I couldn't find this elsewhere, but not sure if I'm using the correct search terms(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the traffic source/medium via utm parameters.

Check out [this page](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) for help in generating the URLs.